Excel Combine Column A from Multiple Worksheets
Currently using Excel 2021 Home Office. I have a sheet named 'Total'.
Goal: Display all the words from Column A , in multiple sheets from Sheet1 to Sheet9.
So it will display words all from Column A into one large concatenated column.

Car
Furniture
Grass
Tree
Ocean...

Originally, had this equation below with TOCOL and VSTACK, but it does not work anymore for some reason (after copying to GoogleSheets and back into Excel). Our office does not allow VBA or PowerPivot. Implement with RangedSheets, instead of listing all 10. Only attempting excel equations. There is a way to do it. Trying to remember. How can I write an equation for this?
=_xlfn.TOCOL(_xlfn.VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet9!A1:A99),1)


May be worth looking at textjoin() then textsplit()

Like this perhaps: =FILTERXML("<m><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",1,Sheet1:Sheet9!A1:A99)&"</b></m>","//b") but this has limitations because of TEXTJOIN() look into using PQ !
